# Error when performing an inner join on Spark 2.0.1 DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Anyone else run into this issue and have ideas on how to work around it?

I have been trying to update my code to use Spark 2.0.1 and Scala 2.11. Everything was working happily in Spark 1.6.0 with Scala 2.10. I have a straightforward dataframe to dataframe inner join that is returning an error. The data comes from AWS RDS Aurora. Note that the foo dataframe below is actually 92 columns and not the two that I have shown. The issue still persists even when there are only two columns.

Pertinent information:

DataFrame 1 with schema

```
foo.show()

+--------------------+------+
|      Transaction ID|   BIN|
+--------------------+------+
|               bbBW0|134769|
|               CyX50|173622|
+--------------------+------+

println(foo.printSchema())

root
|-- Transaction ID: string (nullable = true)
|-- BIN: string (nullable = true)
```

DataFrame 2 with schema

```
bar.show()

+--------------------+-----------------+-------------------+
|              TranId|       Amount_USD|     Currency_Alpha|
+--------------------+-----------------+-------------------+
|               bbBW0|            10.99|                USD|
|               CyX50|           438.53|                USD|
+--------------------+-----------------+-------------------+

println(bar.printSchema())

root
|-- TranId: string (nullable = true)
|-- Amount_USD: string (nullable = true)
|-- Currency_Alpha: string (nullable = true)
```

Joining of the dataframes with explain

```
val asdf = foo.join(bar, foo("Transaction ID") === bar("TranId"))
println(foo.join(bar, foo("Transaction ID") === bar("TranId")).explain())

== Physical Plan ==
*BroadcastHashJoin [Transaction ID#0], [TranId#202], Inner, BuildRight
:- *Scan JDBCRelation((SELECT

        ...
        I REMOVED A BUNCH OF LINES FROM THIS PRINT OUT
        ...

      ) as x) [Transaction ID#0,BIN#8] PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(Transaction ID)], ReadSchema: struct<Transaction ID:string,BIN:string>
+- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, false]))
   +- *Filter isnotnull(TranId#202)
      +- InMemoryTableScan [TranId#202, Amount_USD#203, Currency_Alpha#204], [isnotnull(TranId#202)]
         :  +- InMemoryRelation [TranId#202, Amount_USD#203, Currency_Alpha#204], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
         :     :  +- Scan ExistingRDD[TranId#202,Amount_USD#203,Currency_Alpha#204]
```

Now the error that I get is this:

```
16/10/18 11:36:50 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 6)
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ID IS NOT NULL)' at line 54
```

The full stack can be seen here (http://pastebin.com/C9bg2HFt)

Nowhere in my code or in my jdbc query, pulling data from the database, do I have `ID IS NOT NULL)`. I spent tons of time Googling and found a commit for Spark that adds null filters in the query plan for joins. Here is the commit (https://git1-us-west.apache.org/repos/asf?p=spark.git;a=commit;h=ef770031)

Answer (score 0):

Curious if you have tried the following;

```
val dfRenamed = bar.withColumnRenamed("TranId", " Transaction ID")
val newDF = foo.join(dfRenamed, Seq("Transaction ID"), "inner")
```